Install APK with PackageInstaller fails on Android API 35 device
My code installs an apk using the PackageInstaller.
That works fine on Android Devices with API 34 and below.
But on Android Emulator with API 35 I get this error:
akul.a(190): VerifyApps: APK Analysis scan failed for com.mypackagename
com.google.android.finsky.verifier.apkanalysis.client.ApkAnalysisException: DOWNLOAD_FILE_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION while analyzing APK
Disabling PlayProtect in the PlayStore-App did not help.
The App has the permissions WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES

WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE  is deprecated and has no effect if the targetSDK of the app is 19 or higher. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission

Without a [mcve], it will be difficult for anyone to help you. DOWNLOAD_FILE_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION suggests that there is a permission issue accessing the APK.
